# VPC for a three-level logistic regression

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am building a mixed effects logistic regression model to explore whether or not someone is diagnosed late with a specific infectious disease. My outcome is late diagnosis (yes/no). My data includes a number of patient-level predictors (e.g., age, sex, route of transmission, etc.) as well as data on the clinic where they were diagnosed (level 2) and the local authority (similar to US county) which funds the clinic (level 3).

In addition to my fixed patient-level effects, I would like to determine whether there is any explanatory power added by including clinic and/or local authority as random effects. I am aware of LR tests and AIC/BIC but would also like to look at VPC.

Does anyone know if the latent variable approach proposed [here](https://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/partitioning-variation-in-multilevel-models.pdf) would also work for a three-level logistic regression model?

That is, if I included both clinic and local authority as random effects, could I then assess the VPC of level 3 as: level 3 variance / (lvl 3 variance + lvl 2 variance + 3.29)?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know if the latent variable approach proposed here would also work for a three-level logistic regression model?

Yes, that should work. For clinics (level 2):

$$
VPC_{\text{clinic}} = \frac{\sigma^2_{\text{clinic}}}{\sigma^2_{\text{clinic}} + \sigma^2_{\text{authority}} + \frac{\pi^2}{3}}
$$

while for local authorities (level 3):
$$
VPC_{\text{authority}} = \frac{\sigma^2_{\text{authority}}}{\sigma^2_{\text{clinic}} + \sigma^2_{\text{authority}} + \frac{\pi^2}{3}}
$$